# Godot Game Engine - Add nodes to unloaded scene/level

Tags: godot, gdscript

### The Question

I have a QuestManager which stores quests (and their contained objectives) like so:

- QuestManager

  - Quest A

    - Objective 1
    - Objective 2
  - Quest B

    - Objective 3

Each objective has a position (vec2) and a level name (e.g. "outside"). Objectives do not appear in the world until previous objectives have been completed.

Objective 1 is located "outside" and Objective 2 is located "inside". When Objective 1 is completed "outside", Objective 2 must appear (i.e. create a collectable item, etc.) in the "inside" level.

***How can I make Objective 2 appear in/be added to the "outside" level if this level is not the current level, and hence cannot be accessed using `get_tree().current_scene`?***

### Notes:

- I am currently using `get_tree().change_scene(path)` to switch between levels
- I've also tried to use `get_tree().change_scene_to(packed_scene)`, where
  `var packed_scene =  preload(path).instance()`, but this gives me a blank screen when I try to change scene.
- QuestManager is an autoloaded (singleton) GDScript, and is responsible for checking whether Objectives and Quests are completed
- Quests and Objectives are responsible for managing themselves, including creating and destroying objects in the world.

### Snippets

**Objective.gd (attached to Objective.tscn)**

```
class_name Objective extends Node2D

export var ObjectiveDescription: String = "?"
export var ObjectiveLocation: String = "?"
export var ObjectiveImage: Texture = load("res://assets/gui/exclamation_mark.png")

export var started: bool = false setget set_started, get_started
export var prepared: bool = false setget set_prepared, get_prepared
export var finished: bool = false setget set_finished, get_finished
export var obj_id: int

# Set up things which the objective needs, such as a location, without starting the objective
# Done when added to a Quest 
func __prepare_o__():
    if prepared:
        push_error(str("Objective ", get_id(), " should not be prepared again!"))
    prepared = true
    print("Preparing Objective ", get_id())
    pass

# Start the objective, for example spawning relevant NPCs
func __start_o__():
    if started:
        push_error(str("Objective ", get_id(), " should not be started again!"))
    if !(get_parent().has_method("add_objective")):
        push_error(str("Warning! ", self, " is an orphan Objective! (parent has no add_objective() method)"))
    started = true
    print("Starting Objective ", get_id())
    pass

# Clean-up the objective, for example removing spawned NPCs
func __clean_o__():
    if !finished:
        push_error(str("Objective ", get_id(), " is being cleaned while not finished!"))
    print("Cleaning Objective ", get_id())

func get_id():
    return str(get_parent().get_id() if get_parent() != null else "?:?", ":", obj_id)

func set_started(s):
    started = s
func get_started():
    return started
func get_prepared():
    return prepared
func set_prepared(p):
    prepared = p
func get_finished():
    return finished
func set_finished(f):
    finished = f
```

**Quest.gd (attached to Quest.tscn)**

```
class_name Quest extends Node

export var QuestName = "?"
export var QuestDescription = "..."

export var stage: int = -1 setget set_stage
export var prepared: bool = false 
export var started: bool = false 
export var finished: bool = false
export var quest_id: int = -1
export var quest_type: int = -1

func _init():
    print(get_children())

# Objectives

func add_objective(objective):
    if(objective is Objective):
        if objective.get_parent() != null:
            objective.get_parent().remove_child(objective)
        add_child(objective)
        objective.obj_id = get_child_count() - 1
        print("Added Objective ", objective.get_id(), " to Quest ", get_id())
    push_error(str("Failed to add Objective ", objective.get_id(), " to Quest ", get_id()))
    

func current() -> Objective:
    if stage > get_child_count() - 1:
        push_error(str("quest.stage out of bounds: ", stage, " vs max ", get_child_count() - 1))
    if stage < 0:
        push_error(str("quest.stage < 0 probably caused by incorrect stage tracking (not initialised?)"))
    var result = get_child(stage)
    return result

# Flow

func __prepare_q__(): 
    if prepared:
        push_error(str("Quest ", quest_id, " should not be prepared again!"))
        return
    prepared = true
    print("Preparing Quest ", get_id())

func __start_q__():
    if started:
        push_error(str("Quest ", quest_id, " should not be started again!"))
        return
    started = true
    print("Starting Quest ", get_id())

func __clean_q__():
    if finished:
        push_error(str("Quest ", quest_id, " should not be finished again!"))
        return
    finished = true
    print("Finishing Quest ", get_id())

func __check_objectives__():
    var current = current()
    if current.finished: # Finish off current objective
        current.clean_o()
    if stage + 1 < get_child_count(): # Start next objective
        stage += 1
        current().start_o()
    else: # Report quest as finished
        finished = true
        QuestManager.check_quests()
    pass

# Util

func get_id() -> String:
    return str(quest_type, ":", quest_id)

func set_stage(s: int):
    print("Changing Quest ", get_id(), " stage ", stage, " -> ", s)
    stage = s
```

**QuestManager.gd (attached to QuestManager.tscn)**

```
extends Node

# The flow of quests is as follows:
# 1) Quests are created and added to their appropriate lists
#   Each quests is told to prepare_q
# 2) When an objective is added to a quest prepare_o should be called. 
#   This is the time for the objective to prepare resources it will need.
# 3) When it is time for the objective to begin, start_o is called
#   The objective is now "active".
# 4) When the objective knows it is finished, it marks finished=true and notifies the QuestManager that an objective has been completed
#   The QuestManager tells all quests to check whether their current objective is complete.
#   If the current objective has finished=true, it will be commanded to clean_o
#   The quest will advance to the next objective.
# 5) If the quest detects it is finished, it marks finished=true and notifies the QuestManager
#   If the QuestManager is satisfied, the quest is finished/cleaned (I haven't decided yet)

onready var QuestGroups = $QuestGroups
onready var StudySet = $QuestGroups/Study
onready var SocialSet = $QuestGroups/Social
onready var PersonalSet = $QuestGroups/Personal
onready var FutureSet = $QuestGroups/Future
export var study_index = -1
export var social_index = -1
export var personal_index = -1
export var future_index = -1

enum QuestTypes {
    STUDY, SOCIAL, PERSONAL, FUTURE
}

# Flow #

func notify_quests_objective_completed():
    QuestManager.dump()
    for set in QuestGroups.get_children():
        for q in set.get_children():
            if q is Quest:
                q.check_objectives()
    QuestManager.dump()

func check_quests():
    print_debug("Checking quests")
    QuestManager.dump()
    
    for st in StudySet.get_children():
        if try_clean_quest(st):
            study_index += 1
    for so in SocialSet.get_children():
        if try_clean_quest(so):
            social_index += 1
    for pe in PersonalSet.get_children():
        if try_clean_quest(pe):
            personal_index += 1
    for fu in FutureSet.get_children():
        if try_clean_quest(fu):
            future_index += 1
    
#   for set in QuestGroups.get_children():
#       for q in set.get_children():
        
        ### OOPS! Need to relink this later ^^
        #var q: Quest = set.get_child(set.index)
#           if (q != null) && (q is Quest) && (q.finished):
#               print("Cleaning quest ", q.get_id())
#               set.index += 1
#               q.clean_q()
    QuestManager.dump()

func try_clean_quest(q: Quest) -> bool:
    if (q != null) && (q is Quest) && (q.finished):
        print("Cleaning quest ", q.get_id())
        q.clean_q()
        return true
    return false

func register_quest(quest: Quest, quest_type):
    if(quest is Quest):
        match quest_type:
            QuestTypes.STUDY:
                StudySet.add_child(quest)
                quest.quest_id = StudySet.get_children().size() - 1
                print("Registered quest ", quest, " id:", quest.quest_id, " type:", quest_type)
            QuestTypes.SOCIAL:
                SocialSet.add_child(quest)
                quest.quest_id = SocialSet.get_children().size() - 1
                print("Registered quest ", quest, " id:", quest.quest_id, " type:", quest_type)
            QuestTypes.PERSONAL:
                PersonalSet.add_child(quest)
                quest.quest_id = PersonalSet.get_children().size() - 1
                print("Registered quest ", quest, " id:", quest.quest_id, " type:", quest_type)
            QuestTypes.FUTURE:
                FutureSet.add_child(quest)
                quest.quest_id = FutureSet.get_children().size() - 1
                print("Registered quest ", quest, " id:", quest.quest_id, " type:", quest_type)
            _:
                quest.quest_id = -1000
                print("Failed to register quest ", quest, " type:", quest_type, " quest:", quest)

func id_str(quest_type, quest_id, obj_id ):
    return str(quest_type, ":", quest_id, ":", obj_id)

func get_current(type):
    match type:
        QuestTypes.STUDY, "study":
            return StudySet.get_child(study_index)
        QuestTypes.SOCIAL, "social":
            return SocialSet.get_child(social_index)
        QuestTypes.PERSONAL, "personal":
            return PersonalSet.get_child(personal_index)
        QuestTypes.FUTURE, "future":
            return FutureSet.get_child(future_index)
        _:
            push_error(str("Unmatched get_current(type) ", type))

func dump():
    print("QuestManager dump():")
    var all = []
    all.append_array(StudySet.get_children())
    all.append_array(SocialSet.get_children())
    all.append_array(PersonalSet.get_children())
    all.append_array(FutureSet.get_children())
    for q in all:
        print("  ", q.get_id(), " ", q, " p=", q.prepared, " s=", q.started, " f=", q.finished)
        for o in q.get_children():
            print("    ", o.get_id(), " ", o, " p=", o.prepared, " s=", o.started, " f=", o.finished)
```

Excerpt from one of my GUI pages:

```
func _on_StartButton_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://levels/outside/outside_scene.tscn")
```

Comment: Bear with me here as I'm just trying to get my head around your set-up. How are you implementing "QuestManager" - is it a singleton gdscript or Mono C# script or a 2D scene that is being instanced in another singleton script? In summary, how are you currently implementing QuestManager as it stands at the moment with working objectives? Some code might be good to fully understand your current implementation.

Comment: I've made some edits - let me know if you need anything else (I can the quest_manager.gd script but it would considerably bloat the question)

Comment: I've also now added snippets for Objective, Quest, and QuestManager @pm101

Comment: Thanks - it is rather complex - so I was just looking for mentions of `get_tree().***_scene` in either script snippet but didn't find any - where do these calls related to the scripts ? (As it will help to answer the question)

Comment: Alright, so I added another tiny little snippet - what it really comes down to is how I can store active instances of levels and call methods like add_child() on them... What I meant talking about switching levels was using change_scene("path") vs some other method. I think that change_scene(path) makes a new instance of the scene each time? Which is not ideal as the level should not lose data if the player leaves it as they will have to come back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to change an scene that is not currently loaded.

Let us start with what you already know: you can use autoloads. If I understand correctly you have an autoload that keeps track of which quests have been completed.

This means that when the other scene is loaded, it can check if the quest was completed and spawn the item you want.

*If you do not want to give this responsibility to the scene, then…*

---

Refactor by putting all the calls to `change_scene` et.al. into an autoload. So that everything that wants to change scenes uses the autoload instead of `get_tree()`.

Then you can have the autolod notify the quests that you just changed scene, and they can run any code they have for that scene, such as spawning a collectible there.

---

You may also be interested in resource based communication, which I explained [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/199693/10408) or in taking control of the process of changing scenes, which is explained in the article [Change scenes manually](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/change_scenes_manually.html).